# Infinitesimal version of chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, chain-rule

We know from chain rule:

$$\dfrac{dy_x}{dx}=\dfrac{dy_u}{du}\dfrac{du_x}{dx}$$

Then will the following also be true?

$$dy_x=\dfrac{dy_u}{du}du_x$$

Is there a proof or reasoning behind it?

In limit definition, $dy_x$ represents the quantity which $\triangle{y}$ tends to when $\triangle{x}$ tends to zero. That is, $dy_x$ is zero. Same with $du_x$. By non-standard analysis, $dy_x$ and $du_x$ represents the infinitesimal change in $y$ and $u$ respectively when there is an infinitesimal change in $dx$.

> Edit
>
> Keeping the proof aside, is the infinitesimal version of chain rule mentioned in the question true or false? It seems to me that the [differential article from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)) says it is true.

Comment: I've added the 'differential geometry' tag because those are the people who will actually know.

Comment: Is this so advanced that common people doesn't know?

Comment: What is the meaning that *you* give to $\mathrm{d}y$?

Comment: @stackexchange, kind of. Someone who hasn't studied at least one semester of differential geometry probably won't be able to give you a meaningful answer, unless there's interpretations of $dx$ out there that I'm unaware of. But I object to the term 'common people'. We're *all* common people, and we're all unique, too.

Comment: Notice that in your statement of the chain rule two different functions are both called the same name $y$. This is a common abuse of notation but in my opinion it causes a lot of confusion.

Comment: In limit definition, $dy$ represents the quantity which $\triangle{y}$ tends to when $\triangle{x}$ tends to zero. That is, $dy$ is zero. Same with $du$. By non-standard analysis, $dy$ and $du$ represents the infinitesimal change in $y$ and $u$ respectively when there is an infinitesimal change in $dx$.

Comment: Calculus doesn't require nonstandard analysis. As goblin said, a rigorous approach requires differential geometry. "d$x$" isn't an "infinitesimal", it's a "differential form".

Comment: I haven't studied differential geometry yet.I think we can easily prove my question from non-standard analysis. However I am looking from a proof from standard analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "$dy$ is zero." But certainly your equation makes sense if you interpret $dy$ as a differential form.

For a function $f:M\to N$, the differential $df_x(\Delta x)$ maps tangent vectors $\Delta x$ on $M$ at $x$ to tangent vectors $\Delta f$ on $N$ at $f(x)$; in other words, $df$ is exactly the map from infinitesimal changes in $x$ to infinitesimal changes in $f$.

From linearity of the derivative it follows that $df_x$ is a linear function of $\Delta x$; therefore $df_x$'s action can be written in coordinates as tensor multiplication $[df_x]\Delta x$.

For a composition $f = y \circ u$ the chain rule then reads
$$df_x(\Delta x) = dy_{u(x)}(du_x(\Delta x))$$
or
$$df_x = [dy_{u(x)}]du_x;$$
an infinitesimal change in $x$ is first piped through $du$ to give an infinitesimal change in $u$, then through $dy$ to give an infinitesimal change in $f= y\circ u$.